# Counter App: Button function to trigger various if else messages

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events

I'm building a passenger counter application for buses with vanilla javascript and I'm trying to wrap my head around how, when clicking a HTML DOM Object button, will alter the messages I want to output based on where the count is.

I have an increase and decrease button that increase or decrease the count by 1. Each bus has different passenger capacities, so I've placed each three busses in the navbar (dds, ddsb, mci). When clicking "dds" for example, I want specific messages to be called relative to where the count is. Likewise for other bus models.

```
let messageEl = document.getElementById("message-el")
let countEl = document.getElementById("count-el")
let ddsNavEl = document.getElementById("dds-nav-el")
let ddsbNavEl = document.getElementById("ddsb-nav-el")
let mciNavEl = document.getElementById("mci-nav-el")
let increaseEl = document.getElementById("increase-btn")
let decreaseEl = document.getElementById("decrease-btn")
let increaseFiveEl = document.getElementById("increaseFive-btn")
let decreaseFiveEl = document.getElementById("decreaseFive-btn")
var count = 0

/* BASIC COUNTER FUNCTIONALITY WITH NO SEATING LIMIT WARNINGS */
function increase() {
    count++
    countEl.textContent = count
}

function decrease() {
    count--
    countEl.textContent = count
}

function increaseFive() {
    count += 5
    countEl.textContent = count
}

function decreaseFive() {
    count -= 5
    countEl.textContent = count
}

function reset() {
    messageEl.textContent = "";
    countEl.textContent = 0
    count = 0
    ddsNavEl.style.fontWeight = "normal";
    ddsbNavEl.style.fontWeight = "normal";
    mciNavEl.style.fontWeight = "normal";
} 


/* COUNTER WITH SEATING AND STANDING LIMIT WARNINGS */

function ddsSelect() {

    if (count === 15) {
        message = "you are at full seating capacity"
    } else if (count > 16) {
        message = "you are over capacity"
    } else {
        message = ""
    }
    messageEl.textContent = message
    
    ddsNavEl.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    ddsbNavEl.style.fontWeight = "normal";
    mciNavEl.style.fontWeight = "normal";
}

function ddsbSelect() {

    if (count === 12) {
        message = "you are at full seating capacity"
    } else if (count > 13) {
        message = "you are over capacity"
    } else {
        message = ""
    }
    messageEl.textContent = message

    ddsbNavEl.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    ddsNavEl.style.fontWeight = "normal";
    mciNavEl.style.fontWeight = "normal";
}

function mciSelect() {
    
    if (count === 10) {
        message = "you are at full seating capacity"
    } else if (count > 11) {
        message = "you are over capacity"
    } else {
        message = ""
    }
    messageEl.textContent = message

    mciNavEl.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    ddsNavEl.style.fontWeight = "normal";
    ddsbNavEl.style.fontWeight = "normal";
}
```

Comment: side note: it's a good practice to include a semi-colon after each line.

Comment: THANK YOU. I knew I had to do something with objects or methods. This makes sense, thanks for the explanation. I'm excited to work with this and implement it!

I'm 2 months into self-learning javascript on my spare time so pardon the poor code structure. I recall the importance of the semicolon in a javascript.info lesson. Appreciate the reminder.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't include all of your functions in this example, but essentially I think the best way to do this would be to create an object and instantiate it per bus, either based on its type or id of some kind.  You mentioned in your example that there were three types of bus... "dds, ddsb, and mci" but essentially by using this technique you could simply instantiate more instances of the object if you needed to setup another bus at some point in the future.

Example below, all of these functions could be setup to accept html elements to update various interface elements.  None of that is included because none of it was provided.

```js
let bus = {
  passengers: 0,
  increase: function() {
    this.passengers++;
    console.log(this.passengers);
  },
  decrease: function() {
    this.passengers--;
    console.log(this.passengers);
  },
  increaseFive: function() {
    this.passengers += 5;
    console.log(this.passengers);
  },
  decreaseFive: function() {
    this.passengers -= 5;
    console.log(this.passengers);
  }
};

// bus types dds, ddsb, mci

let ddsBus = Object.create(bus);

ddsBus.increase();
ddsBus.increaseFive();

let ddsbBus = Object.create(bus);

ddsbBus.increase();
ddsbBus.increaseFive();
ddsbBus.increase();

let mciBus = Object.create(bus);

mciBus.increase();
mciBus.increaseFive();
mciBus.increase();
mciBus.increase();

console.log("dds : " + ddsBus.passengers);    //expected value: 6
console.log("ddsb : " + ddsbBus.passengers);  //expected value: 7
console.log("mci : " + mciBus.passengers);    //expected value: 8
```